# Last query in SQL Zoo, SELECT Tutorial

Tags: mysql, sql

There's a single table of `world` with these columns:
`continent`, `name`, `population`, and more...

The query is:
Some countries have populations more than three times that of any of their neighbours (in the same continent). Give the countries and continents.

The solution is:

```
SELECT name, continent FROM world x WHERE
 population > ALL
 (SELECT population*3 FROM world y
 WHERE y.continent = x.continent
 AND y.name != x.name)
```

I don't understand the last part `y.name != x.name`. I actually don't get 100% why you need `y.continent = x.continent` either in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have a correlated sub-query.

It ensures that you stay within the same continent (`y.continent = x.continent`) and do not compare any country with itself (`y.name != x.name`).

Comment: Ok I understand the `y.continent = x.continent`, but why do we have to explicitly tell the it not to compare itself.

Comment: Because a country is **not** it's *neighbor* even if it's located on the same continent. If you decide to create a list of your neighbors, would you include yourself?